# Jest - a worker process has failed to exit gracefully

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await, jestjs

I really need help with this problem. First, my code is here: https://github.com/cheryllium/fullstackopen-bloglist/tree/92e4538ff1ba6cc9caa99f35fc501be67bc4e224

Since adding the file tests/users_api.test.js, I am now getting a warning from jest that says:

```
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.
```

I found an issue (https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11354) that seemed related but I'm not sure, because nothing has worked to silence this warning. Things I tried:

1. Adding a teardown.js file with `module.exports = { process.exit(0) }` and adding "globalTeardown": "tests/teardown.js" to my package.json under jest settings.
2. Using the hack in the issue to set FORCE_EXIT_DELAY
3. Running with --runInBand option

With all of these, I'm still getting the same warning.

Running the tests with --detectOpenHandles does not produce different output, so that wasn't helpful.

Can anyone help me figure out why this warning is happening and how to get rid of it?

Comment: why don't you just close mongoose connection after all the tests have completed. Like you did in your blog_api.test.js?

Comment: Wow that was simple, thanks!